# How to use dropdown behaviors using Semantic-UI for Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic-UI for Meteor. Let's say I have a dropdown like this:

```
<div class="ui floating dropdown labeled search icon button">
  <i class="world icon"></i>
  <span class="text">Select Language</span>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item">Arabic</div>
    <div class="item">Chinese</div>
    <div class="item">Danish</div>
    <div class="item">Dutch</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And initializing it like this:

```
Template.DropdownTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    this.$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown()
})
```

But how do I reach the behaviors of that dropdown, which, according to the documentation on the Semantic-UI site, look like this:

```
$('.your.element')
  .dropdown('behavior name', argumentOne, argumentTwo)
;
```

An example is this `clear` behavior:

```
$('.ui.dropdown).dropdown('clear')
```

This simple behavior doesn't work (nor does any other behavior) in Meteor for some reason. Callbacks work, but not the behaviors.

Does anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your issue. Please note that there is a syntax error in `$('.ui.dropdown).dropdown('clear')`, try `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('clear');` instead. I also tested with `$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('restore defaults');` and both worked.

Comment: Weird. Meteorpad is down so I can't give an example. It's not because of a typo, it definitely doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please share a repository on GitHub?

Comment: What package did you try with? I use `semantic:ui` which may have updated several times since I installed it. Unfortunately it's impossible to update because it will mess up my entire design.

Comment: I used `semantic:ui` version 2.1.8.